# Фильтрация UITableView c данными из списка .plist

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, iphone

Есть таблица, заполняется она из списка `*.plist`, который основан на словарях (`NSDictionary`),
примерно такого формата:

```
<array>  
    <dict>  
        <key>name</key>  
        <string>Example1</string>  
        <key>type</key>  
        <string>1</string>  
    </dict>
    <dict>  
        <key>name</key>  
        <string>Example2</string>  
        <key>type</key>  
        <string>2</string>  
    </dict>    
</array>
```

Вопрос: можно ли при нажатии на одну из кнопок `UISegmentedControl`, отфильтровывать
таблицу и выводить только данные с типом "1"?  
П.С.: с выводом всех данных из списка проблем нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну и в качестве добавления к лаконичному "*конечно можно*" [[@aknew](/users/2088/aknew)](/users/2088/aknew), покажу, каким ещё способом это можно сделать:

```
NSArray *array; // массив, полученный из plist'a
NSString *type = @"1"; 
NSArray *result = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate: 
                           [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(type == %@)",  type]];
```

*(iOS 3.0+, OS X 10.4+)*

---

Хотя лично я бы *заранее* распихал по отдельным массивам объекты с разными типами - так должно быть быстрее, чем вытаскивать их каждый раз из одного общего.

Comment: шикарно! вечером опробую =)  Тоже думал, над тем, чтоб распихать объекты с разными типами по разным массивам, скорее всего так и сделаю, спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: @Kobayashi_Maru а можно даже и не по разным - так к ним тяжелее обращаться на самом деле - а, например, в словарь, где под ключами `"1"`, `"2"`, ... будут лежать массивы нужных вам объектов.

Comment: воспользовался пока разными массивами, все получилось, потом со словарем попробую.
Спасибо за наводку)

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно, я бы при нажатии на кнопку пробегал по всему массиву и выбирал нужный тип в другой массив и уже на его основании строил таблицу. Учитывая, что с таким способом хранения массив не слишком большой, не думаю что это займет много времени.